# numbers of disjonts sets

Tags: combinatorics

(1) Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The total no. of unordered pairs of Disjoint subset of $S$ is ... ?

(2) Let $X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The no. of different ordered pairs $\left(Y,Z\right)$ that can be formed such that

$Y\subseteq X\;,Z\subseteq X$ and $Y\cap Z = \varnothing\;,$ is ... ?

Comment: Thanks for formatting your question nicely. BTW, the empty set can be written using `\emptyset`: $\emptyset$, or using `\varnothing`: $\varnothing$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) $\dfrac{3^5 - 1}{2} + 1$

2) $3^5$

An element is either in $Y$ or $Z$ or neither. Use this to get the answer.

Comment: How can you Get it would you like to explain it. Thanks

Comment: If it's ordered, then we have 3 choices on where to put each element In X or in Y or in neither of them. Since all choices are independent, we get 3*3*3*3*3 possible ways. In the unordered case, do a similar thing and avoid overcounting.

Comment: Sorry I meant Z instead of X in the comment.

Comment: I formatted your answer ($LaTeX$) (I usually don't like to edit answers! I hope you don't mind.) - Try to use such formatting in your answers, or at least return to your answer to format it.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I don't really know how to use Latex. Do you know where I can learn to use it?